# Why doesn't this PHP Contact Form Send An Email?

Tags: php, html

This is a really basic question, but I can't figure it out at all. When this PHP form is submitted, it does not send an email and I don't know why. I hope you guys can help.

```
<?php 
if($_POST['submit']){
    $to = "email@email.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    header( 'Location: http://example.com' ) ;
    }
?>
```

```
    <container class="form">
      <table class="formtable" align="center">
        <form action="formcontact.php" method="post">
          <tr><td align="center" class="tabletitle">Name:</td></tr><tr class="space"><td align="center"><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
          <tr><td align="center" class="tabletitle">Email Address:</td></tr><tr class="space"><td align="center"><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
          <tr><td align="center" class="tabletitle">Message:</td></tr><tr class="space"><td align="center"><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea></td></tr>
          <tr><td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
      </table>
    </container>
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error? try `if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) { echo 'sent' } else { echo 'not sent' }`

Comment: maybe it is because of the missing form tag? Were you ever able to send mails from your server? Are you sure that mail ist installed and ready to fire?

Comment: are you trying to do it on localhost?

Comment: Check your smtp settings..

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file

**form action=""** method="post"

should do the trick( if of course you're including your HTML in php)

Answer (score -1):

Check this way:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['submit']){
    $to = "email@email.com";
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $message = $name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
     if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
       echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
       header( 'Location: http://example.com' ) ;
     }else
     {
            echo "Mail failed to Sent";
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: It will just hide the message if mail is not sent, it won't explain why the mail isn't sent...